Quotes in the Qur'an
If the Qur'an, as it claims, is a linguistic miracle inimitable by mankind or jinn, then how can it quote anyone. Let me put it with examples:
In Surah Taha (from verse 25), the Prophet Musa (ﷺ) says the following in response to Allah giving him the mission to preach to the Pharaoh:

قَالَ رَبِّ ٱشْرَحْ لِى صَدْرِى ٢٥ وَيَسِّرْ لِىٓ أَمْرِى ٢٦ وَٱحْلُلْ
عُقْدَةًۭ مِّن لِّسَانِى ٢٧ يَفْقَهُوا۟ قَوْلِى ٢٨ وَٱجْعَل لِّى
وَزِيرًۭا مِّنْ أَهْلِى ٢٩ هَـٰرُونَ أَخِى ٣٠ ٱشْدُدْ بِهِۦٓ أَزْرِى
٣١ وَأَشْرِكْهُ فِىٓ أَمْرِى ٣٢ كَىْ نُسَبِّحَكَ كَثِيرًۭا ٣٣
وَنَذْكُرَكَ كَثِيرًا ٣٤ إِنَّكَ كُنتَ بِنَا بَصِيرًۭا

But these verses have rhyme, rhythm, and of course it does, it's the Qur'an. But they are the words of the Prophet Musa (ﷺ), so did he speak in such incredible eloquence? Of course here, I suppose, he didn't speak Arabic, so Allah can just paraphrase it from the ancient Egyptian language into Arabic.
But then what about the whole starting of Surah al Jinn. It's some Jinn during the time of the Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) speaking, and that too with eloquence. Now, since they were at the time of the Prophet (ﷺ), understood the Qur'an's Arabic, they probably did speak in Arabic, right? So would this disprove the Qur'an?
The Jinn that spoke, spoke before the Surah was revealed obviously. I hope I am able to explain it properly, but if these were words of a Jinn, that is also in the Qur'an, wouldn't this show that a Jinn produced verses similar to the Qur'an?
Arab poets were struggling to find a single word that could be improved in the Qur'anic text, so it's pretty impressive for a Jinn to do multiple verses. And I don't think Allah would paraphrase this, since if it was in Arabic, then Allah shouldn't, because what He says is absolutely true in all respects.
If you say that the Jinn did speak in a language other than Arabic, then is there any Hadith that proved Jinn did use a language outside Arabic in Arabia. Or perhaps Jinns lived long enough that they would still resort to some ancient dead language, but still understood Arabic alongside because Arabic was used amongst the humankind.
So this can be disproven if there is some hadith to show one of the following:

A direct response: A Hadith where the Prophet (ﷺ) answers this questions (pretty unlikely I suppose)
A Hadith where the Prophet (ﷺ) says that Jinns knew other languages outside Arabic.
A Hadith saying Jinns lived forever
A Hadith saying Jinns lived for a very long time

It would be better for the higher one in the list to be answered, as the higher ones can be used as a more plausible explanation.
If there is any other way to disprove this "Jinn's words in the Qur'an" claim, it would be fine as well as long as it's explained. I hope to get an answer to this question, because I can't, so thanks to whoever can help.

Many fancy solutions instead of the obvious one: Quotations aren't word-for-word but rather paraphrased to fit the Quran's purpose in the context.

I wanna understand. Did Allah paraphrase what the Jinn said in Arabic?

Quotations are almost never word-for-word, either in the Quran or in normal speech.
This is blatantly obvious in translated quotations (which Allah does not even keep consistent between Surahs and fits each to the context of its passage), but is also true of Arabic quotations.
First thing to understand is: What is the point of a quotation?
The point is to convey to the audience what someone said. Most of the time, you are trying to convey the meaning of what they said, and rarely, you are trying to convey the exact wording of what they said.
In hadith sciences, we prefer people keep quotations as precise to the original wording as possible because a narrator can misunderstand what was originally meant and change it to convey an incorrect meaning to the audience.
In the Quran, Allah is not concerned with misunderstanding anything. He is all-knowing and He conveys the accurate meaning of what people said without needing to stay loyal to their wording. Rather, Allah fits the quotations to the context of His speech in terms of vocabulary, rhythm, and rhyme.
As for translated quotations, it is very easy to see how Allah words them to fit the context while conveying the same meaning because Allah requotes the same speech multiple times in different wording.
One example:

امْكُثُوا إِنِّي آنَسْتُ نَارًا لَعَلِّي آتِيكُمْ مِنْهَا بِقَبَسٍ أَوْ أَجِدُ عَلَى النَّارِ هُدًى
إِنِّي آنَسْتُ نَارًا سَآتِيكُمْ مِنْهَا بِخَبَرٍ أَوْ آتِيكُمْ بِشِهَابٍ قَبَسٍ لَعَلَّكُمْ تَصْطَلُونَ
امْكُثُوا إِنِّي آنَسْتُ نَارًا لَعَلِّي آتِيكُمْ مِنْهَا بِخَبَرٍ أَوْ جَذْوَةٍ مِنَ النَّارِ لَعَلَّكُمْ تَصْطَلُونَ


⟪Stay here; indeed, I have perceived a fire; perhaps I can bring you a torch or find at the fire some guidance.⟫ (20:10)
⟪Indeed, I have perceived a fire. I will bring you from there information or will bring you a burning torch that you may warm yourselves.⟫ (27:7)
⟪Stay here; indeed, I have perceived a fire. Perhaps I will bring you from there [some] information or burning wood from the fire that you may warm yourselves.⟫ (28:29)

Firstly, He changes the word used to refer to the torch. Secondly, He switches the order of items. Notice how ⟪information⟫ is translated as ⟪guidance⟫ and placed at the end in Surah Taha to fit the rhyme of the passage. Possibly, ⟪information⟫ and ⟪guidance⟫ were both mentioned by Musa (AS) and Allah kept one in some passages and the other in others.
Musa (AS)'s original statement was of the same meaning but not necessarily the same wording or even order.
Unlike translated quotations which are repeated often, I do not know of an example of an Arabic quotation being repeated. So, it requires more analysis to show the same for them.
Consider Allah quoting Waleed ibn al-Mughirah in Surah Muddathir with the verse before and after it:

ثُمَّ أَدْبَرَ وَاسْتَكْبَرَ
فَقَالَ إِنْ هَذَا إِلَّا سِحْرٌ يُؤْثَرُ
إِنْ هَذَا إِلَّا قَوْلُ الْبَشَرِ
سَأُصْلِيهِ سَقَرَ

If you look at the rest of the Surah, it also follows a similar rhyming pattern with the ر at the end.
Clearly, Allah paraphrased Waleed to fit the Surah while conveying what he said "This is just magic, and it is made up by a human, Muhammad (SAW)."
This fact was also not lost on the scholars and transmitters of history. That is why several narrations mention what Waleed actually said in a different wording from the Quran:

وَإِنَّ أَقْرَبَ الْقَوْلِ فِيهِ؛ لَأَنْ تَقُولُوا سَاحِرٌ، جَاءَ بِقَوْلٍ هُوَ سحر يفرِّق به بين المرءِ وابنه، وَبَيْنَ الْمَرْءِ وَأَخِيهِ، وَبَيْنَ الْمَرْءِ وَزَوْجَتِهِ، وَبَيْنَ الْمَرْءِ وَعَشِيرَتِهِ. فَتُفَرِّقُوا عَنْهُ بِذَلِكَ
The best you can say about him is that he is a magician: He brought magical speech that divides between a man and his son, a man and his brother, a man and his wife, and a man and his family. So, dissuade people from him by saying that.
(Seerah Ibn Hisham 1/243)

